# Mysql count how many answers are correct

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `user_answers` :

```
id | quiz_id | user_id | question_id | choosen_answer_id |
1  |    1    |    2    |      1      |        5          |  
2  |    1    |    2    |      2      |        6          |  
3  |    1    |    2    |      3      |        7          |  
4  |    1    |    3    |      1      |        5          |  
5  |    1    |    3    |      2      |        8          |  
6  |    1    |    3    |      3      |        9          |
```

I want to `cont` how many correct answers (same `choosen_answer_id` for same `question_id` ) has user with `user_id = 3` compared with `user_id = 2` on same `quiz_id`

In this example I should receive `1` because user with `user_id = 3` answered correct only on question with  question_id=1 (for user_id = 2, question_id = 1 choosen_answer_id = 5 and for user_id = 3, question_id = 1 choosen_answer_id = 5`).

Thanks

Comment: How to know whether the answer is correct or not?

Comment: "correct are answers" are from `user_id = 2 ` but it does not matter. Мaybe "correct are answers" is not in place, and my question should be: count how many answers are same for same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you are willing to count for how many questions both users have given the same answer. You could self-join the table as follows :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS number_of_identical_answers
FROM user_answers ua2
INNER JOIN user_answers ua3 
    ON  ua3.user_id           = 3 
    AND ua3.quiz_id           = ua2.quiz_id 
    AND ua3.question_id       = ua2.question_id 
    AND ua3.choosen_answer_id = ua2.choosen_answer_id
WHERE ua2.user_id = 2
```

If you want to display  the joined records instead of counting them, you can change `COUNT(*)` to a list of columns from tables `ua2` (answers of user 2) and `ua3` (answers of user 3).

Answer (score 0):

```
select user_id, count(*)
from table1 t1
join (select *from table1 where user_id = 2) t2
on t2.question_id = t1.question_id
where t2.choosen_answer_id  = t1.choosen_answer_id 
group by t1.user_id
```